# What kind of SATA do I have?

Tags: hard-drive, sata

This may seem like a noob question, but here goes. I need to buy a new HD for my Sony Vaio laptop. My old one has a SATA hard drive, with two rows of connectors, one with 7 pins, another with 15. Are all SATA HDs like this? Will any SATA HD work for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 15 pin connector is for power, the 7 pin connector is for data. ALL sata drives are forwards and backwards compatible, so any sata drive will work.

Naturally you'd want to use a drive as fast as your connection is, and get a standard 2.5 inch drive (as opposed to a overheight one) rather than a 3.5 inch drive